# im trying to fix the error from babel someone have idea how i can fix it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

hello im trying to connect to my code another code that someone gave me and when im trying to paste it im getting error

```
./node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/index.web.js 3:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import "./reanimated2/js-reanimated/global";
| export * from "./reanimated2";
> export * as default from "./Animated";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a known issue in the latest version as discussed [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3464)

Reverting the react-native-reanimated package version back to 2.6.0 or 2.3.1 should fix the issue.